# Non-stationary data ( simple linear regression )

Tags: regression

i am trying to find the correlation between GDP and solid waste generation and recycling in all Chinese provinces, i have collected the data from 1999-2017 and i am using average data of all provinces at one year, for instance, average all provinces in 1999 till 2017. and i am using a linear regression model to do the correlation, my question is shall my data be stationary or its ok with non-stationary data, however when i converted the data into stationary using log and first difference, new data values have negative values, and the correlation does not exist like the case of using non-stationary data.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Right now, this is pretty unclear.  What is "average data"? My blog post [how to ask a statistics question](https://statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/) may help you formulate it so it can be answered.

Answer (score 0):

When you use linear regression on non-stationary time series, there is a big risk of spurious correlation. E.g. You will see a strong relation between the population of China and the Dow Jones stock averages over the last 100 years.

When you are trying to find the correlation between two variables you almost never want this sort of thing. Otherwise, everything that goes up is correlated positively with everything else that goes up, and negatively with everything that goes down.